# Converting a multi-line text file to a python string

Tags: python, string

I have a text file that has a sequence of four characters a,b,c,d which is 100 lines long that I want to convert to a text string.

There are lines in the txt file that have asterisks that I want to skip entirely.

Here is an example of how the txt file can look.   Note the third row has an asterisk where I want to skip the entire row

```
abcddbabcbbbdccbbdbaaabcbdbab
bacbdbbccdcbdabaabbbdcbababdb
bccddb*bacddcccbabababbdbdbcb
```

Below is how I'm trying to do this.

```
s = ''
with open("letters.txt", "r") as letr:
        for line in letr:
            if '*' not in line:
                s.join(line)
```

Comment: Are you trying to preserve line breaks, or do you want one long string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
s = ''
with open("letters.txt", "r") as letr:
        for line in letr:
            if '*' not in line:
                s += line
```

builtin type [`str.method`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable. you should use `s += line` for contacting string one by one.

Iterate a text file is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Need to use `readlines()` function.

This is an example, please modify it yourself.

```py
s = ''
with open("letters.txt", "r") as letr:
       result = letr.readlines()

print(result)

for line in result:
    if '*' not in line:
        s += line 
        print(line)

print(s)
```

I looked at other answers and found that I made a mistake,  your code `s.join(line)` -->  `s += line`  is ok.